# What does "over time" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have problem understanding this:

> Over time, this is a fragile approach.

What does "over time" mean here? Thanks!

Comment: A little more context would help.

Comment: it means `long term`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Over a number of weeks/months/years" .

The implication is that whilst the approach might be acceptable if it is only for a short time, if it is applied for a long time it will cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is  explained in Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary. It means that 'as time passes'. Some dictionaries say that 'gradually'. So,the above-mentioned answer focusses the 'fragile' and it will be 'fragile' as 'as time passes'.